# WPF - Bound Control Not Updating When Property Changed?

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

I've bound the Text property of a TextBox to a base object's property and it seems to work just fine.  Unfortunately, when I programatically change the value of the property, it doesn't seem to update on the GUI.

Here's the property:

```
public string SealedDate
{
    get
    {
        string result = string.Empty;

        if (_DACase.SealedDate != DateTime.MinValue)
        {
            result = Formatting.FormatDate(_DACase.SealedDate);
        }

        return result;
    }
    set
    {
        DateTime theDate = DateTime.MinValue;

        if (DateTime.TryParse(value, out theDate)
            && _DACase.SealedDate != theDate)
        {
            _DACase.SealedDate = theDate;
            base.OnChanged(); //fires event so I know the value of the object has changed
        }
    }
}
```

And the value of that property is being set when another property it being set:

```
public bool IsSealed
{
    get
    {
        return _DACase.SealedId > 0
            || _DACase.SealedDate != DateTime.MinValue;
    }
    set
    {
        if (value != (_DACase.SealedId > 0 || _DACase.SealedDate != DateTime.MinValue))
        {
            if (value)
            {
                this.SealedId = Authentication.CurrentUser.Id;
                this.SealedDate = Formatting.FormatDate(DateTime.Now);
            }
            else
            {
                this.SealedId = 0;
                this.SealedDate = DateTime.MinValue.ToString();
            }
            base.OnChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

And the XAML of the TextBox that isn't updating when I think it should:

```
<TextBox Name="txtSealedDate" Text="{Binding SealedDate}" Grid.Column="5" Grid.Row="3" IsReadOnly="True" />
```

Comment: What does `OnChanged` do? Could you please post its code? Does your class implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`? WPF has basically 2 ways to know that the property is changed: either the property has to be a `DependencyProperty` (which is not the case for your code), or the containing class has to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`.

Comment: OnChanged() only fires an event.  Nothing fancy at all.  The event is then handled to let me know whether or not my save button should be enabled.  My class does not implment `INotifyPropertyChanged`.  I'll take a look at that now.

Comment: `INotifyPropertyChanged` did the trick. If you'd like to put in an answer to my question, I'll give you the credit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vlad's solution (in the comments) was correct.

Comment: It's a bit late now, but Vlad's comment was actually a question rather than some example code that provided a solution.  It'd be great if you could update this answer with "what actually worked".